# How to select items and move from one list box with datasource to another?

Tags: c#, listbox

```
listBox2.DataSource = listBox1.SelectedItems;
listBox2.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
listBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
```

After using the above code, I am not able to select one by one. Help!
some one please post codes to remove too

Comment: You need to update the other listbox data source by adding an item to it, not directly as list item.

Comment: :S why dont you just listBox2.DataBind() ?

Comment: @Bastardo its working with data source, a small change is needed

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to define a model for your Listbox :

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

After you can set items like this :

```
listBox2.Items.Add(new MyModel() { Id = 1, Description = "description" });
listBox2.DisplayMember = "Description";
listBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
```

And now, your listbox will show the description property. If you select an item, the SelectedValue in listbox2 will be the value of id property

Comment: If this answers what is asked, I didn't get the question. +1 for nice modeling.

Comment: please see the edited code, i need to load listbox 2 with list box one selected items.

Comment: listbox2.Items.Add(listbox1.SelectedItem); To add the selected item in the other listbox

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlDataAdapter to dump data into the listbox from the data source and based on the data selected in one of the listbox use listbox.add() method, Use a "for" loop to dump the data from one listbox to another using an index.

```
for(int i=0; i<listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(listbox1.SelectedItems[i].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
        listBox2.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
        listBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
```

this is working fine....